# Access TextView in ViewPager from Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an Activity with a ViewPager containing multiple fragments. how can i now access a TextView in one of that fragments to change its text from the main activity? I tried multiple ways and they all ended in a NullPointerException.

Activity:

```
public class SummonerOverview extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements TabListener, OnPageChangeListener {


    private ViewPager mPager;
    private PagerAdapter mAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.summoner_overview);

        initialize();   
    }

    private void initialize() {

        // initialize Pager
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);


        }
}
```

PagerAdapter:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        frags = new Fragment[3];
        frags[0] = new StatisticsFragment(0);
        frags[1] = new RatingsFragment(1);
        frags[2] = new HistoryFragment(2);
    }

    private final int NUM_PAGES = 3;
    Fragment[] frags;

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        if (arg0 == 0)
            return frags[0];
        else if (arg0 == 1)
            return frags[1];
        else
            return frags[2];
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }

}
```

The Fragment:

```
public class StatisticsFragment extends SherlockFragment {

public StatisticsFragment(int fragNr) {
        this.fragNr = fragNr;
    }

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overview_statistics, container, false);

        return v;
    }

}
```

The Textview in the StatisticsFragment is labeled with an id in the fragment_overview_statistics.xml, but when i try

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_of_the_textview)
tv.setText("text");
```

from within the onCreate() Method of the Activity after the initialize() Method, i get an Exception.

Comment: Trying to look for that `TextView` in the `onCreate` method(which you shouldn't do) in the first place is incorrect as the `Fragments` will not be available there. If you need to set the text at that moment then move the setting of the text directly in the fragment class.

Comment: When is the first time the Fragment (and therefore the tv) is available? After the activity is full running (after onResume)?

Maybe its just a designproblem of me. I want to display some Data I fetched from the internet. I start with creating the Activity, Viewpager and Fragments. After that, i start an AsyncTask to fetch the Data from the internet and write the parsed Data to to TextViews in the onPostExecute() Method of the AsyncTask.

Comment: If that is what you're doing I would go with the solution in your answer. As you require to set the `TextView` for all(I presume) fragments just rebuild them. In the `onResume` method the fragments should be available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after another hour of googling, i think i solves my own question (although i'm sure there is a better method to solve that)

I now hold all the Data that is displayed by the fragments in the MainActivity and make the Fragmets consume this Data in their `onCreateView()` Method by using public Methods of the Activity.

In the PagerAdapter, i overwrote getItemPosition() to:

```
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

Now, everytime i update some of the Data, i also call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` which leads into a recreation of all fragments.

It works, although it looks like a poor hack for me. Im sure there must be a better solution because now i have to recreate all fragments for changing one TextView of one Fragment, what is surely not the way it is intended to be done.